How do I check if set of solutions to differential equation form vector subspace
Let $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ be the vector space of all functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, with addition and scalar multiplication defned pointwise. Which of the following sets of functions form a vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}?$

The set of solutions of the differential equation
$\ddot{x}(t)+(t^2-3)\dot{x}(t)+t^4x(t)=0.$
The set of solutions of $\ddot{x}(t)+(t^2-3)\dot{x}(t)+t^4x(t)=\sin
t.$
The set of solutions of $(\dot{x}(t))^2-x(t)=0.$
The set of solutions of $( \ddot{x} ( t) ) ^4+ ( x( t) ) ^2= 0.$

I already know that there's a theorem homogenous linear diff. equations being vector spaces, but without it how exactly do I verify each case manually?
I suppose I can solve each one and write down the general solution, but I read that there are infinite number of solutions. So how do I verify if axioms hold if there's possibly infinite solutions to check?

Check the axioms directly. I like to check the zero vector first then closure of addition and scalar multiplication.

You can apply the usual characterisation of subspaces: Check that $0$ is a solution to the equation; then take any solutions $x(t), y(t)$ (no need to find them explicitly, work formally) and verify that $ax(t)+by(t)$ is a solution to the equation too, for every $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$.
If you get stuck at some point and you suspect for some equation the set of solutions is not a subspace, try to find some $x(t),y(t), a,b$ such that $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are solutions but $ax(t)+by(t)$ isn't.

Like with any subspace question you have to make sure , a)zero is in it, with f, r*f is in it and with f and g f+g are in it.
